# Visual Studio Build Error:requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

If I open visual studio build and then build again I always get this error.

```
  requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped
```

then I have to restart visual studio and go through it all over again. This just recently started happening any ideas why ?

Machine - Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108306/visual-studio-2010-build-fails-to-file-copy-error).  One possibility is the Visual Studio Achievements extension.

Another possibility [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/msbuild/thread/ad04e42b-69d4-4372-a655-47d61f01ffb0) related to having the same 3rd party assembly referenced twice with different hint paths.

Comment: Visual Studio Achievements extension was in fact the issue! TY so very much! I was going CRAZY!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this was happening randomly i.e. sometimes the program succeeded and gave the said error in a few runs. I found that the records in xml document were being iterated and in each iteration the records were being edited and saved. I changed this logic to save the file once after all the records are edited and poofff.. the error is gone.