# How can I fix this visual studio error? "The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10

I am getting this error for various DLL's which are outputs of projects in my solution.

Things I have tried:

- Restarting PC multiple times
- Closing visual studio
- Turning off all visual studio extensions
- Deleting the files manually in the explorer. I get the error "The action can't be completed because the file is open in another program"
- Using ProcessExplorer to find processes that are using the DLL's. It does not find any processes
- I have tried using ResourceMonitor and WhoLockMe as well, to no avail
- I have killed the explorer.exe process and that didn't work either
- From command line I ran 'git reset --hard HEAD' to revert to the last commit (which was a stable build)

Any other ideas how I might be able to unlock these files?

Update: Turns out that some of the DLL's in every solution that I opened with Visual Studio yesterday are permanently locked

I do not have Visual Studio Achievments installed and I have disabled all extensions. Closing open documents did not help.

Comment: Sounds like it may be a virus?  Can you try another machine or a VM?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Build Error:requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055858/visual-studio-build-errorrequested-operation-cannot-be-performed-on-a-file-with)

Comment: @Mikael that did not answer my question.

Comment: @JoelFan I can build the solution when I clone it from the repo into a different folder. I still can't delete the DLL's though

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the issue solved itself after I did the following:

- Clone the project into a different folder
- Build and run the cloned project with Visual Studio

A few hours of programming later I tried to delete the files and they were no longer locked